# Undefined Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

if some elements/value in an array in javascript is undefined, does that make the array undefined?

And please how do you check if every element/value of an array is undefined in javascript?

Comment: someone downvoted you because the question doesn't show much research - these are very basic javascript concepts. i wouldn't downvote you because you're a very new user, but many people do.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: thanks alot. i did do my research but i couldnt find an answer to "if some elements/value in an array in javascript is undefined, does that make the array undefined?"

Comment: simplest way - go into console (browser or node) and type `a = [undefined, 1, 2]` then check if a is undefined or not. interpreters are easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not make the entire array undefined if only a single element was undefined.

If you want to check each element, simply loop through them and test each element for undefined.